# Allow Outgoing Traffic Through Port

Tags: firewall, ubiquiti-edgerouter

I have the ERL3, and am needing to connect to a couple of MySQL Databases that use port 3306.

I have looked at my firewall rules with `show firewall >  myoutput.txt` and port 3306 is not blocked or being utilized by any other services.

What do I need to do so that protocol on this port is allowed out of my network?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be blocked, if for example your INPUT/FORWARD/OUTPUT policy is drop by default.
You can easily check  by adding following statement to your iptables to the router.  I assume you have a PC within a local network

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s your.int.IP  -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

and make sure your output policy also allows it

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

I presume you have access to outside world.  If you are connecting from the same computer just use the latter statement, and try. If your INPUT policy is blocking you can additionally add following statement (only if connecting from same PC as firewall)

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

test is out